# Launching another node child process with a different version

Tags: node.js, electron

The newest stable version of Electron is only on node 14.x. Is it possible to fork a child process to run on node 16.6.1?

The child process needs to be running node 16.6.1 for compatibility with a module. One solution I considered was running a bash script or similar to launch the other node app, but using `child_process` allows me to get information back from the child.

Comment: What kind of module has that requirement? _Although I know of Discord.js being one._

Comment: @KelvinSchoofs exactly it is Discord.js

Comment: Not entirely sure why you'd use that in Electron.  I'd suggest using a lower version if possible. You _could_ wait for Electron to switch to Node v16 but knowing them, that'll take a very long time. There's [this issue](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/30448) _(which might be by you)_ you can follow up. Otherwise my answer about using `child_process` or the `node` NPM module is all that's left, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could indeed use the `child_process` module and give it the path to the v16.6.1 `node.exe`. This would mean the user of your Electron app needs to have that version installed, and you need to find the path somehow.

Alternatively, you could use the [`node`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node) package, which basically packages Node.js as a module. The documentation is quite lacking though.

Comment: It's a bandaid, but using the `node` package to make a node executable is working for now.